# Routes and controller methods for a multi step form are not correct, it appears "The page has expired due to inactivity"

Tags: php, laravel

I have a multi step form using bootstrap and jQuery. The multi step form is for a user to buy a product. There are 4 steps: 
- Step 1 is for the user insert his info (name, email, etc)
- Step 2 the user select the payment method
- Step 3 the user introduces the payment data
- Step 4 present an invoice for the user.

So I want to divide the form in 4 steps, each step with a respective method in the PaymentController. But the routes or controller methods should have some error because Im getting "`The page has expired due to inactivity`" when "go to step 2" button is clicked. Do you know where is the error?

**The flow of the context is:**

The user clicks in a product and goes to the product details page. In the product details page the user select the quantities. So there is a select menu inside a form with this action "`<form method="post" action="{{route('products.storeProduct', ['id' => $product->id, 'slug' => $product->slug])}}">`".

The route for this form is and to present the payment page:

```
Route::post('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeProduct',
    'as'   =>'products.storeProduct'
]);
Route::get('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@presentPaymentPage',
    'as'   =>'products.payment'
]);
```

In the PaymentController, the storeProduct method stores the product, get some info from db and then redirect the user to the products.payment route to present the payment page page:

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function storeProduct(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
        ...
        return redirect(route('products.payment',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
    }

    public function presentPaymentPage(Request $request, $id, $slug=null){
      ...
        return view('products.payment',
            ['product' => $product, 'id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]);
    }
}
```

So now the user is on the payment page. In this page appears the mult is step form, the first step is step 1 in this first step appears a form for the user introduce somer user info like name, email, etc. The action of the form is for the storeUserInfo() method where the information introduced by the user should be stored in session. Code in the payment.blad.ephp for step 1:

```
 <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="step1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <h6>User Info</h6>
            <form method="post" action="{{route('products.storeUserInfo', ['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug])}}">
                <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                    <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" required class="form-control"  value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
                </div>
                <!-- other form fields -->
                <input type="submit" href="#step2"
                        class="btn btn-primary btn float-right next-step" value="Go to step 2"/>
            </form>
        </div>
```

In the `PaymentController` I added two methods:

```
public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
    dd($request->all()); 
}
public function presentPaymentMethods(Request $request, $id, $slug=null){
}
```

And in web.php two routes:

```
Route::post('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment/storeUserInfo', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeUserInfo',
    'as'   =>'products.storeUserInfo'
]);

Route::get('/product/{id}/{slug?}/payment/paymentMethods', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@presentPaymentMethods',
    'as'   => 'products.presentPaymentMethods'
]);
```

When user click in "Go to step 2" he is redirected to ""store.test/product/5/a-5/payment/storeUserInfo";" but it appears "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again". Do you know where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have missed the CSRF protection as I can't see it on your form: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf

Comment: Thanks, now it appears a blank page, do you know why?